# How can I tell what frame model/year this bicycle is?

Tags: road-bike

There is a bicycle that is locally owned that I want to buy and the only information I have about the bicycle frame from the dealer is that it's just a OCLV 110. With a couple of zoom-ins and research, I *think* this is Trek 2002 5900 USPS bike, is this correct?[This is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLx1N.jpg)

Comment: can you clarify: is the picture of the bike you are talking about or a picture of what you have guessed the bike to be?

Answer (score 2):

[Bikepedia](http://Www.bikepedia.com) is a good resource for indentifying models, year and spec levels.

Answer (score 0):

The way of telling is different for every brand and model. Usually, by a combination of serial numbering, or color of the frame, you can sometimes figure it out.

There is not enough information present in the picture to determine for sure exactly what that bike is.